# (Cocos2d) Where to place autoRemoveOnFinish when using a particle system?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a fire particle system on my football in my game and I am wondering where I should place the optimizing code (autoRemoveOnFinish). This is how I am doing it right now.

interface

```
CCParticleSystem        *_fire;
@property (readwrite,retain) CCParticleSystem *fire;
```

Implementation

```
self.fire = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"fire.plist"];
self.fire.position = cpv(self.contentSize.width * .5, self.contentSize.height * .5);
self.fire.positionType = kCCPositionTypeGrouped;
_fire.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
[self addChild:_fire z:0];
```

If this is right the way I am doing it why are the fps dropping to around 25. I am only allowing 5 footballs to be created on the screen at one time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where or when you enable autoRemoveOnFinish. The important point is that this only works for one-time effects, like CCParticleExplosion. One-time effects have their duration property set to a positive value.

If you're having framerate problems I bet that the totalParticles (max particles in Glyph Designer) value is set too high. You may be having only 5 particle effects running, but each particle system may spawn hundreds of particles.

And the size of each particle (respectively its texture) also has a great impact on performance.

Comment: So are you saying that autoRemoveOnFinish is not going to do anything for me? If so, is there another way to make it more efficient if I leave it the way that it is? Each fire emitter on the footballs has about 200 to 300 Particles. Is that too many?

Comment: Probably, but your device will be the judge of that obviously. Try lowering the particle amount and see what happens.

Comment: I changed the amount of particles emitted from 200 to 100 and the texture that I am using is only 4KB in size. I am still dropping to the low 30 fps with 5 footballs on the screen at once. Is this about as good as I am going to get it?